# Count the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ( $f$ is determined by its value on $\mathbb{Q}$)

Tags: real-analysis

A continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ is completely determined by its values on $\mathbb{Q}$. Use this to count the continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I know that since $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is completely determined by its values on $\mathbb{Q}$ but I don't understand why the question is asking to count the continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I mean constant functions are also continuous but that's uncountable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Keep in mind that there are different orders of infinity.  Could the set of these continuous functions be countable?  Well, no...you've already pointed out that the constant functions have the same cardinality as the reals.  So, then...does the set of continuous functions have the same cardinality as the reals or is it bigger?

Comment: Is the question asking for the cardinality of the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I guess that the exercise wants you to obtain the cardinality of the set $C=\{f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: f\mbox{ is continuous}\}$. By your comment with the constant functions, you already know that $|C|\geq |\mathbb R|$.

Comment: @AndréPorto Yeah!,  this can be done without using the former statement. I have one more question: What's the link? It has mentioned  "use this"

Comment: @DerekAllums Yeah! It says "use this" and that's confusing me, this could have done without using the former statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say they probably want you to realize that there are not too many continuous functions.

Of course, there is at least continuum of them, because you have constants.. However, the fact that they are determined by values on $Q$ shows that there are no more than $2^\omega$ of them (compared to the set of all functions from $R$ to $R$, which is $2^{2^\omega}$).

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks a lot :)